# Find if pair of elements with given sum exists in large integer array

Tags: c#

I'm having a integer array of 10 Million elements, how to write a function in C# which returns True if the array has a pair which sums up to 75.

My code is:

```
        int sum = 75, max = 10000000;
        int[] array = new int[max];
        bool checkFlag = false;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rnd.Next(0, max * 20);
        }
        Array.Sort(array);
        if (array[0] + array[1] <= sum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", array[0], array[1], array[0] + array[1]);
            checkFlag = true; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum upto 75 is: " + checkFlag);
```

Comment: First sort the array, and then use binary search on pairs?

Comment: _Why_ do you have to do this? Is there any use for it or is it just a programming exercise?

Comment: @Cyral: Why would that matter?

Comment: This will take a long time via brute force search. What kind of time can this take?

Comment: @EdS. Knowing the reasoning behind something is good so we can provide better examples and advice for a specific problem.

Comment: This will take a long time any way. A lot less if the array contain only positive elements (since you can first filter only those <= 75).

Comment: do you also need to shpw the index position of both number?

Comment: By pair you mean exactly two elements.. right? consecutive or non-consecutive? And the method should return as soon as at least one pair is found.. correct? Last, but not the least, is the array already sorted? I am afraid you'd say no :)

Comment: What is the highest sum, one would be asked to search using this function? Could it be arbitrarily large.. or relatively small (for example - below 100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if the array is sorted.

```
public bool ContainsPair(int[] array) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = array.Length - 1;
    while(i < j)
    {
        if (array[i] + array[j] == 75) 
            return true;
        else if (array[i] + array[j] <  75) 
            i++;
        else if (array[i] + array[j] >  75) 
            j--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You use two pointers and walk towards the middle of the array. Pointer `i` starts at the beginning of the array, while `j` starts at the end. If you find two numbers that sum up to 75, you return true. If the sum is less than 75, then you move pointer `i` one step towards the middle and check again. If the sum is more than 75, you move pointer `j` one step towards the middle and check again.

If the two pointers meet, then you return false, because no pair was found.

This is O(n), not including sorting the array.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bucketing problem.  You want buckets of 0s to pair with 75s, 1s to pair with 74s, etcetera.  Bucketing is a Dictionary jobby.  A `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` gives you a result in O(n) amortized.  If you only care about a bool result then a `HashSet<int>` is good enough.  You can't get better than O(n).

```
    static bool PairExists(int[] arr, int sum) {
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (int elem in arr) set.Add(elem);
        foreach (int elem in set)
            if (set.Contains(sum - elem)) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

If the array is likely to contain the pair then you could consider testing after the Add() call, still O(n).

Comment: The for loops makes it O(n).  The HashSet operations are O(1).

Comment: HashSet operations are at best O(1) if there are no collisions. O(N) if not. Depends on the hash algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the numbers are positive, you can do this:

1. Create a boolean array of 75 elements.
2. Walk the list of 10,000,000 items.  When you see one that's 75 or less:

   - check to see boolean arry has an entry at element 75 - that number.  If it does, you found a match.
   - otherwise, set the nth entry of the boolean array.

Example C#:

```
        var bits = new bool[75];
        foreach (var n in intArray)
        {
            if (n <= 75)
            {
                var diff = 75 - n;
                if (bits[diff - 1])
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Found pair: {0} and {1}", n, diff));
                    break;
                }
                bits[n - 1] = true;
            }
        }
```

But if the numbers in the array can be any valid integer, including negative numbers, you can do something like this:

```
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (var n in intArray)
        {
            if (n <= 75)
            {
                var diff = 75 - n;

                if (set.Contains(diff))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Found pair: {0} and {1}", n, diff));
                    break;
                }
                set.Add(n);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This trivially breaks down without further limits. What if there are values -200 and +275?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a brute force search.

```
public bool hasPairOf(int[] a, int sum)
{
   for(int i=0; i < a.length-1; i++)
   {
      if(a[i]+a[i+1] == sum)
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could create an enumerator and use LINQ.

```
public static IEnumerate<int> toSums(this int[] a)
{
   for(int i=0; i < a.length-1; i++)
   {
      yield return a[i]+a[i+1];
   }
}
```

Now you can do the following.

```
a.toSums().Any(pair=>pair == 75);
```

Both should have the same performance. If you ask why? that's because C# will only execute the enumerator until the `Any` condition is true. The `toSums` function uses the `yield` keyword to create an enumerator that is only executed when it is evaluated.

**EDIT:**

To find any pair of values in an array that sum to 75 and not just adjacent. I would do it using nothing but LINQ for easier reading.

```
function bool hasPairOf(int[] a, int sum)
{
    var nums = a.Where(val=>val <= sum)
                .Select((v,i)=>new{value=v,index=i})
                .ToArray();

    return (from a1 in nums
            from a2 in nums
            where a1.index != a2.index
                  && a1.value+a2.value == sum
            select true).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Not quite, he never said the elements had to be sequential. This is the approach I was going to take though.

Comment: This only check adjacent pairs, which is still O(n) .. but doesn't work without further restrictions.

Comment: oh! Any **pair**! Ah. That is a different story.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Not too bad, but you have increased the execution time by doing the "ToArray" first (especially if all the numbers are <= 75). "Brute force" should just do the self join (or a nested for loop, which is what I would have done) for "maximum" speed (even though it will still be quite slow).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int max = 10000000;
            const int sum = 75;

            var data = new int[max];

            var rnd = new Random();

            bool found = false; 
            int c = 1;
            Stopwatch sw;

            while (!found)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                {
                    data[i] = rnd.Next(0, max*25);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Took {0}ms to create the array", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var check75 = new HashSet<int>(data.Where(x => x <= 75));
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Took {0}ms to create the hashset", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
                {
                    if (check75.Contains(sum - data[i]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ", i, data[i]);
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Took {0}ms to check75", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                Console.WriteLine("Loop #" + c++);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finish");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need pair should be <75, not single value.

Answer (score 0):

Add the compliment of the sum in a Dictionary, if it doesn't have it. If dictionary already has the compliment then a pair exists for the given sum.

```
    public bool HasPair(List<int> arr, int sum)
    {
        var track = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            if (track.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
                return true;
            
            track.Add(sum - arr[i], arr[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }
```